# CentOS7 KVM - Mouse is "off" on the console with virt-manager

Tags: linux, redhat, kvm-virtualization, vnc

I am managing a KVM host with virt-manager from a Windows 8.1 PC.  I have XMING\PuTTY installed on the PC w\ X11 Forwarding.  I SSH to the KVM host and run `virt-manager`.

I noticed that the mouse is noticeably off on the console and it makes clicking hard, especially on Windows guests.  Sometimes the guest mouse is diagnoially offset about 1/4 a screen from my real mouse.  It's not that big of a deal as my goal is to get RDP up as fast as possible but it still very annoying.

Another [possibly unrelated] issue is that when using the default Spice display device it will often cause Xming to crash and `virt-manager` to core dump.  I have to switch the display device to VNC.

Any advice?

Comment: Use a Linux desktop. Windows is not an ideal platform for managing Linux systems.

Comment: While it is not ideal, it is certainly doable. I typically use MobaXterm for my home lab (KVM on Centos 7) without issues and I was able to VPN in and do the same from putty (which I had never tried before) with no issues either. Can you X11 forward into other linux hosts fine? And does the offset go away or is it the same when you switch the device to VNC?